# How to update category Front-end in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make post edit page front-end in wordpress , I can show all the categories with this code

```
                    <?php
                    $include = array();
                    $categories = get_terms('category', array(
                        'include' => $include,
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                    ));

                    $categories_count = count( $categories );
                    if ( $categories_count > 1 ) :
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-categories">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                                echo '<li class="form-categories-item"><input type="checkbox" id="post_cat-' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '" name="post_category[]" value="' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '" /><label for="post_cat-' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . esc_attr( $cat->name ) . '</label></li>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

how can I add **checked** tag to selected categories when creating post?

thanks

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305740/update-category-from-the-front-end-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code below :

```
<?php
    $include = array();
    $categories = get_terms('category', array(
        'include' => $include,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    $categories_count = count( $categories );

    // get post categories
    $post_cats     = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
    $post_cats_arr = array();

    foreach ( $post_cats as $post_cat ) 
    {
        $post_cats_arr[] = $post_cat->term_id;
    }

    if ( $categories_count > 1 ) :
?>
    <div class="form-categories">
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach ( $categories as $cat ) 
                {
                    $checked = '';

                    if ( in_array( $cat->term_id, $post_cats_arr ) ) 
                    {
                        $checked = 'checked';
                    }

                    echo '<li class="form-categories-item"><input type="checkbox" checked="' . $checked . '" id="post_cat-' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '" name="post_category[]" value="' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '" /><label for="post_cat-' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . esc_attr( $cat->name ) . '</label></li>';
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!